# Hide all fields of a multi select using jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I would like to know if it is possible with jQuery to hide ALL fields of a multi select, whatever their value is.

What I would like to do later, is to display some of these fields depending on what fields are selected in another multi select of the same page.

The link between the two multi selects' elements are in a HashMap sent to the page using a servlet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does hashMap look like?

Comment: String -> ArrayList<String>
Category1 -> Subject1, Subject2, ...

Multiselect 1 contains Category list and the second the subjects of the categories that are selected.

Comment: please provide sample code we can work with- not abstract. Also a better detail of behavior wanted. `hide` will not work cross browser